# Help with this 2 variables limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I'm asked to calculate this limit:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+x)+\ln(1+y)}{x+y}
$$

After calculating iterated limits and using some directions ($y=\lambda x$ and $ y=\lambda x^2$) all I can deduce is that the limit is actually $1$, but using polar coordinates I'm not able to prove it. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Taylor series? Your logarithms de facto are from single variable.

Comment: The expression is not defined for all $(x, y)$ near $(0, 0)$.

Comment: Try the path $y=-x$...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+%28ln%281%2Bx%29%2Bln%281%2By%29%29%2F%28x%2By%29+at+%280%2C0%29

Comment: @BobDobbs The natural domain over  ${\bf R}^{2}$ of $f(x,y)=\frac{\log(1+x)+\log(1+y)}{x+y}$ is the set $\{(x,y): x>-1, y>1, x+y\not=0\}$. So, over that domain we can not use the path $y=-x$ because that path is not in the domain.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\alpha \neq 0$ and choose the following path $s=x+\alpha x^2, t=-x+\alpha x^2$.
\begin{eqnarray}
{\log (1+s)+\log(1+t) \over s+t} &=& { \log ( (1+\alpha x^2)^2 - x^2)  \over 2 \alpha x^2 } \\
&=& { \log ( (1+\alpha x^2)^2 ( 1 - {x^2 \over (1+\alpha x^2)^2 } ) )  \over 2 \alpha x^2 } \\
&=& { 2\log (1+\alpha x^2)  \over 2 \alpha x^2 } + { \log ( 1 - {x^2 \over (1+\alpha x^2)^2 } )  \over 2 \alpha x^2 } 
\end{eqnarray}
A little L'Hôpital shows that the limit as $x \to 0$ is
$1-{1 \over 2 \alpha}$.

In particular, the limit in the question does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the path $y=\frac1{1+x}-1$:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)+\ln\left(1+\frac1{1+x}-1\right)}{x+\frac1{1+x}-1}=
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1+x)}{x+\frac1{1+x}-1}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong answer. I did not delete for I was asking things in the comments.**

If you're allowed to use Taylor series, then here is another way: consider

$$\ln(1+x) \sim x - \dfrac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)$$

and the same for $\ln(1+y)$, clearly when $x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$.

In this way we have:

$$\lim_{(x, y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x - \dfrac{x^2}{2} + y - \dfrac{y^2}{2}}{x+y} = \dfrac{x+y - \dfrac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}{x+y} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(x+y)^2- 2xy}{x+y}$$

Now

$$ \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(x+y)^2- 2xy}{x+y} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[ x+y - \dfrac{2xy}{x+y}\right]$$

Since $x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$ we can think of them as two infinitesimals (say $\epsilon$) hence

$$\dfrac{2xy}{x+y} \sim \dfrac{2\epsilon^2}{\epsilon} = 2\epsilon \to 0$$

Whence your limit is $1$.

Comment: The limit of $\frac{2xy}{x+y}$ does not exist. Consider the path $y=0$ and $y=-x+x^2$

Comment: @AVK Ah, your're right. Well, I have always had huge problems with two variables limits. The umpteenth proof :D

Comment: @AVK Just to learn: how do you find the pathologic path? I mean if I analyse $y =mx$ path here, I get $\dfrac{2mx^2}{x(1+m)}$, whence limit should be zero for all $m$ hence path-independent. How to see "all" the paths?

Comment: I once had to write thirty test assignments on calculus of multivariable functions :) With the limits like $\dfrac{2xy}{x+y}$ this is simple : there can be problems where the path approaches the set on which the denominator is zero. As for the original limit, there you can see the path where the numerator is zero (and the denominator is not)

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, I realised that. I do not delete the answer for I was asking AVK some questions.